# Issue with Material Style in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I have this small example that does not work as i expected :

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.2

Window {
    id: root
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    property bool lightTheme: false
    Material.theme: Material.Dark
    Material.foreground: Material.color(Material.Red) // value is always material red #F44336 (from light theme)

    onLightThemeChanged: {
            Material.theme = lightTheme ? Material.Light : Material.Dark;
    }

    Button {
        id: btn
        width: 200
        height: 200
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "change theme"

        onClicked: {
            lightTheme = !lightTheme;
        }
    }

    Text {
        id: darkRed
        text: "predefinedDarkThemeRed"
        color: "#EF9A9A"
        anchors.top: btn.bottom
        anchors.horizontalCenter: btn.horizontalCenter
    }

    Text {
        id: lightRed
        text: "predefinedLightThemeRed"
        color: "#F44336"
        anchors.top: darkRed.bottom
        anchors.left: darkRed.left
    }
}
```

The issue is with the default `Material.Red` color being always picked from the `Material.Light` theme whatever theme i have selected.

However, when i don't set any `Material.foreground`, then it is white with the `Material.Dark` and dark with the `Material.Light`, and dynamically switched between those colors when the theme is changed, so everything is fine.

I would expected the same behaviour with a custom `Material.foreground` but it does not seem to work.

What is wrong here ?

Thank you.

Note: the app is run with options -style material args, and i am using Qt 5.9.3 or Qt 5.10.1

Comment: Please try `Material.foreground: Material.color(Material.Red)`

Comment: Thanks, i have edited the question ( but it does not change anything )

Answer (score 0):

i think you missed a little nuance

add in .pro file

```
QT += quickcontrols2
```

in mine file add QQuickStyle::setStyle("Material");

```
#include <QQuickStyle>
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
        {
            QGuiApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
            QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
            ................
            QQuickStyle::setStyle("Material"); 
            //The style can also be specified as a path to a custom style, such as
            //QQuickStyle::setStyle(":/mystyle");
            ................

            return app.exec();
        }
```

in your example, the result will be
[image]

when pressed
[image]

Comment: Thanks, did not try yet. When you click the button, does the "CHANGE THEME" color change ?

Comment: From what i see in your second picture, the color remain unchanged. Maybe you have uploaded the wrong one ?

Comment: I put the wrong photo, after clicking changes  Material.Light and  Material.Dark

Comment: write on skype i will help you, vahag19874

Comment: Look at your picture, the background has changed from light to dark theme but the text color is still the same...

Comment: to change text color  button, add this             Material.foreground= lightTheme ? Material.Red : Material.Blue;  in  onLightThemeChanged:

Comment: Of course i can do everything manually but this is not exactly what i have asked